# jQuery, ajax POST method success returns: Undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**my script code:**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
    var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/TestPage.aspx/SystemEdit")%>';
    var ip = $('#editIP').text();
    var loc = $('#txtBay').val();
    var team = $('#txtTeam').val();
    var port = $('#txtPort').val();
    var xcel = "", office = "", moni = "";                                   
    var parameter={ "ip": ip, "loc": loc, "team": team, "port": port, "excel": xcel, "office": office, "monitor": moni}

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: pageUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
        contentType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data,success,error) {
            alert("Error:" +error);
        }
    });           
});
```

my code behind c# code is:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SystemEdit(string ip, string loc,string team, string port, string excel,string office, string monitor)
{
    return "The Current Time is: "+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

my page name is : TestPage.aspx

While clicking the save button I'm getting 'undefined'. I'm not getting the current time from code behind c#.

Comment: `contentType: 'json',` specifies you are expecting return result as `json` but you are passing it as `string`. Change `contentType: 'text'` and check once!

Comment: What is the content - type of the result,  and have you verified that it returns what you expect,  when accessing it through a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return json result as below:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("The Current Time is: "+ DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

also put below attribute above method:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

And as you specified json format you should write:

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

By the way you should use a Webservice  here!

Comment: Use `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Comment: I rewritten the contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",. Now it's working fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess setting a `json` content type should be done this way:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vs2013 then make sure you disable the below line in route.config to get things working.

```
 'settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
```

My VB Code Behind:

```
  <WebMethod()>


       Public Shared Function GetReport(ByVal Data As String) As String
          Try

                Return "Hello" + Data

            Catch ex As Exception

                Return "Failed"
      End Try
End Function
```

Js Script :

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
  var char = $(this).text();

 var SendData = {};
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "TEST.aspx/GetReport",
      data: JSON.stringify(SendData),
      data: "{ 'Data': '" + char + "'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
          $('#lbl_test').text(data.d);
      },
      error: function (data, success, error) {
          alert("Error:" + error);
      }
  });
 });
```